# Error SQL71624: The permission 'CONNECT' is not valid for the target object 'guest' in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloud, dac, azure-database-mysql

I have a SQL database created and I am trying to deploy/move that database to the Azure Cloud by using the Deploy Database to SQL Azure Wizard in SQL Server Management Studio. But I have ran into an error after trying to deploy it. I am using the SQL Authentication to log in with my credentials. I also tried installing the Data Migration Application.

### The error is:
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
Error SQL71624: The permission 'CONNECT' is not valid for the target object 'guest' in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

---

BUTTONS:

OK

I don't understand what this error means and also I don't understand why this error is happening. I looked on the internet for possible solutions but could not find any information. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure Sql Database and regular SQL Server aren't entirely compatible.

One of the things that is enabled on regular SQL Server is the `guest` login. This login allows connection to instance, with a default database of `master`. Once connected, the user can switch to a different database (`use [thedatabase]`) if they have the authority to do so.

But in SQL Azure, you connect directly to a single database, and can't switch databases on the connection. So the `guest` account has no function.

On your *source* instance (the one you want to migrate), you can revoke this ability so that the wizard won't try to migrate it. Execute `revoke connect from guest` on your on premise instance.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for all your explanation and your help! It makes a lot of sense now.